# How to pass more than one criteria to Criteria.elemMatch() Api?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have a situation that I want to provide 3 conditions in `elemMatch` method call provided by `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria` Api.

`Inventory` collection looks like this -

```
{
    "_id" : "H-P3NCDST45"
    "booking" : [
    {
        "updateDate" : ISODate("2018-01-29T13:32:03.789Z"),
        "status" : "STARTED",
        "message" : "abc"
    },
    {
        "updateDate" : ISODate("2018-01-29T13:32:04.789Z"),
        "status" : "PENDING",
        "message" : "def"
    },
    {
        "updateDate" : ISODate("2018-01-29T13:33:04.789Z"),
        "status" : "CONFIRMED",
        "message" : "abc"
    }
]
}
```

I want to do something like below query. Fetch all documents from `inventory` collection which have at-least one embedded document in `booking` array whose status is "STARTED" and `updateDate` is between `<start>` and `<end>` date, i.e. Fetch all booking from inventory which are started/initiated between given `<start>` and `<end>` date.

```
db.inventory.find({"booking": { $elemMatch: { status: "STARTED",updateDate: { $gte: ISODate("2018-01-01T14:04:34.447Z"), $lte: ISODate("2018-01-20T14:04:34.447Z")}}}})
```

Criteria Api provides `criteria.elemMatch(Criteria c)`. **How to pass multiple criteria in this `elemMatch(c)` method call?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
Criteria criteria = 
   Criteria.where("booking").
   elemMatch(
      Criteria.where("status").is("STARTED").
      and("updateDate").gte(date1).lte(date2)
   );
```

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks. I tried with more than 2 criterias and it works as well:                
    elemMatch( new Criteria().andOperator( Criteria.where1...., Criteria.where2...., Criteria.where3....,))